# Как определить закрыта ли крышка ноутбука

Tags: c#, .net

Как в C# определить, закрыта ли крышка ноутбука?
Нужно, чтобы программа выполняла действия только при закрытой крышке.

Answer (score 6):

Великий и могучий приходит на помощь:

> In Vista you can register for a callback for when the Lid Close Action changes. This is done by calling `RegisterPowerSettingNotification` (see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373196.aspx for details). The GUID for this power setting you're interested in is GUID_LIDCLOSE_ACTION. This is defined in `wdm.h` in the Platform SDK.
>
> Once registered, a `WM_POWERBROADCAST` will be sent to your application with `wParam` set to `PBT_POWERSETTINGCHANGE`. This event is sent anytime the value for the lid close action changes. The `lParam` contains a pointer to a `POWERBROADCAST_SETTING` structure (see http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372723.aspx) containing information on the setting change.

([отсюда](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tabletandtouch/thread/0bbf90be-9322-47fb-bfa4-016b57211b3a))